# Read Column data from CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file

```
Name,Age,Data
Test,22,Yes
Test2,23,No
Test3,43,Yes
```

How can I process this file using PowerShell, so that I can replicate this functionality:

```
foreach(var HeaderName in CSV.HeaderName)
{
   //Sample value Name

   foreach(var data in HeaderColumn.Data)
   {
      //Do Something with data 
      //Sample values as we loop through will be
      //Test,Test2,Test3
   }
}
```

Where `CSV.HeaderName` should be having the values `Name`, `Age`, `Data`
and `HeaderColumn.Data` will have the column data for `Name`, `Age` and `Data` as we process the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PowerShell equivalent of your pseudo code would be something like this:

```psh
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv'

$headers = $csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | select -Expand Name

foreach ($header in $headers) {
  foreach ($data in $csv.$header) {
    # do stuff with $data
  }
}
```

For better answers take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $csvfile = 'C:\temp\test.csv'
PS C:\> Get-Content $csvfile
Name,Age,Data
Test,22,Yes
Test2,23,No
Test3,43,Yes
PS C:\> $csv = Import-Csv $csvfile
PS C:\> $csv | Format-Table -AutoSize

Name  Age Data
----  --- ----
Test  22  Yes
Test2 23  No
Test3 43  Yes

PS C:\> $headers = $csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | select -Expand Name
PS C:\> $headers
Age
Data
Name
PS C:\> foreach ($header in $headers) {
>>   foreach ($data in $csv.$header) {
>>     Write-Host $data
>>   }
>> }
>>
22
23
43
Yes
No
Yes
Test
Test2
Test3
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How Do I get the $data value. When I write to host $data it does not display anything.

Comment: @user1221989 The code worked when I tested it with your sample data. Please provide evidence.

Comment: If inside the first foreach I add $header it displays the value of the header like Name but in the second foreach if I add $data it does not display the value of the data which should be Test,Test2,Test3

Comment: @user1221989 Again, please provide evidence. Edit your question and show the actual code you're running and the actual data you're processing.

Comment: I am just running your code and using the exact csv file as in the question.

Comment: I noticed that if in the second loop we do foreach($data in $csv){ $data.$header  } then it works

Comment: That solves my issue. Thanks for the help Ansgar. I think you also have helped me a lot in the past with my VB script questions.